# Draw 3D model at coordinates in C# xna?

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

i'm drawing several primitives with a camera class that supplies with view, world and projection. With these i can move the camera and see all 3 of my primitives. The problem is that i now wan't to add a 3d model in the project, but the ways i know of to draw a 3d model won't work with the camera class. I have tried using:

```
Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[mymodel.Bones.Count];
        mymodel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in mymodel.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {

                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *
                    Matrix.CreateRotationY(0.0f)
                    * Matrix.CreateTranslation(modelposistion);
                effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosistion, Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
                effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, aspectRatio, 1.0f, 10000.0f);
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
```

But this draws the model in the center of the screen, while i want it stationary, so i can view other models in the same project.

Any help to how this can be achieved?

Comment: As said in the title, i want to place the model at COORDINATES in the world.

Comment: As long as `modelposition` is constant, the position in world space should stay the same. Are you saying that the model moves as the camera moves? This can hardly be the case with the above code.

Comment: that is exactly what i am saying. As i move the camera, the model follows.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem: "as you move your camera, the model follows".

Most likely, it isn't following, you are just moving the camera without changing where the camera is "looking at". Your view matrix calls for it to look at (camera to be pointed at) Vector3.Zero no matter what position the camera is altered to. This means that if your model position does not change, and your view matrix is always looking at the same world location, then the model will not appear to change position. It may get bigger or smaller or you might see it from different angles, but it will always be in the same spot on your screen. It's because your telling the camera to always look at the same position in your world.

Changing the camera position isn't enough to freely look around your world, you must also change where the camera is looking at ( the 2nd param of the View matrix).

Also, it is best to think of the camera as having just a view and projection matrices. The world matrix should be thought of as part of (or supplied by) the model.